# checking if datagrid has values

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am working on a C# project which includes WPF. I was wondering, If I could somehow check If my **data grid** contains certain element.

For example,
I have **combo box** whose itemsSource is some list of objects. Now, when an user selects an item from the combo box and presses the button[image: Before click]

below in data grid (in same window) that item shows up.[image: After clicking]

**I want to forbid the user to select same item more than once and for example put MessageBox with error message. How could I do that?**

**Code**

This Window:

```
public partial class AvioWindowAddNEdit : Window
{
    Avio avio;
    public enum Stage { ADD, EDIT};
    Stage stage;

    public AvioWindowAddNEdit(Avio avio, Stage stage = Stage.ADD)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.avio= avio;
        this.stage= stage;

        textboxCode.DataContext = avio;



        comboboxListofFlights.ItemsSource = Aplikacija.Instance.Flights;
        comboboxListofFlights.DataContext = avio;


        datagridListofFlights.ItemsSource = avio.ListofFlights;




        datagridListofFlights.ColumnWidth = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Auto);

        if (stage== Stage.EDIT)
        {
            textboxCode.IsEnabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Button which adds selected item to data grid:

```
private void btnAddFlight_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        avio.ListOfFlights.Add(comboboxListOfFlights.SelectedItem as Flight);

    }
```

Singleton class for loading in all of my data:

```
class Aplication
{
    public ObservableCollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Airport> Airports { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Flight> Flights{ get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Avio> Avios { get; set; }

    public string LoggedInUser { get; set; }

    private static Aplication instance = new Aplication();

    public static Aplication Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }

    private Aplication()
    {
        Users= new ObservableCollection<User>();
        Airports = new ObservableCollection<Airport>();
        Flights = new ObservableCollection<Flight>();
        Avios= new ObservableCollection<Avio>();
        FillInData(); //method where I filled in all of these ObservableCollections
    }
}
```

My class:

```
public class Avio : ObservableObject, ICloneable
{
    //observableobject is an object where I implemented INotifyPropertyChanged
    private string code;

    public string Code
    {
        get { return code; }
        set { code= value; OnPropertyChanged("Code"); }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Flight> listOfFlights;

    public ObservableCollection<Flight> ListOfFlights
    {
        get { return listOfFlights; }
        set { listOfFlights= value; OnPropertyChanged("ListOfFlights"); }
    }


    private bool active;

    public bool Active
    {
        get { return active; }
        set { active= value; OnPropertyChanged("Active"); }
    }

    public Avio()
    {
        active= true;
        ListOfFlights = new ObservableCollection<Flight>();
    }
    public Avio(string code)
    {
        active= true;
        ListOfFlights = new ObservableCollection<Flight>();
        Code= code;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code behind this? How are you adding the values to the `DataGrid`?

Comment: Datagrid is used for displaying information from some source (i.g. list, dataset, etc.). So you need to forbid adding data to your source. This can depend from source you use, so any code will be desirable for we can help you..

Comment: [http://prntscr.com/lljp2l] - constructor of this window.
**CbListaLetova** is my combo box defined in xaml file which holds binding path to a property called ListaLetova, defined in my class [prntscr.com/lljnm6].
[http://prntscr.com/lljpe7] - button which adds selected item from combo box to data grid (I wanted here to add some condition for doing this)
Aplikacija.Instance.Letovi is a ObservableCollection made for loading all my data [http://prntscr.com/lljrzi] @miamy

Comment: Please do not post a code as screenshots. Imagine someone wants to model the situation - what should he/she do? Re-type code from pictures? Please edit your post and add to it code snapshots themselves. Thanks.

Comment: I just did it @Miamy

Comment: I found the solution, sorry for bothering @Miamy

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) as an ItemsSource for your DataGrid. In that way you'll always have easy access to the data via code.
Check out [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-create-and-bind-to-an-observablecollection) tutorial as a starting point (this uses ListBox instead of DataGrid, but it's easily adaptable to DataGrid).

Comment: I am already using ObservableCollection. I have singleton class which loads in all of my data [http://prntscr.com/lljt10]